# is it possible to create hooks on several vertices simultaneously?

Tags: vertices

I'm trying to create hooks on all randomly selected vertices, but I can't.
Is there a way to do this?

Explaining a little better...
I am studying the most effective way to animate realistic human models and change masses of human organs by parameters. For that, I need a method capable of associating human organs to the skin that is generated in the MB-LAB add-on. This way I hope that when changing the character's pose in the MB-LAB the human organs are also moved / animated and for that I thought of using the hooks, because after the change of pose in the MB-LAB the human organs must follow the movement.

Some observations:
1- I have already used the rigging and skinning process to do this, but it is not a very effective method, because the human model I am working with has 312 objects and adjusting the influence weights for so many objects is an unfeasible process.
2- I am trying to associate this animation method with MB-LAB, because I need the parametric modeling tools of the add-on, as I will need to create "fat" and "thin" humans.
3- Is there another method of associating parametric modeling and posture changes in anatomically correct models?

Comment: Hello, where are you stuck exactly in the process ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I explained my problem better.